# ¿Por qué pandas modifica el tipo de dato de las columnas de mi DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, visualización-de-datos

Qué tal, soy nuevo en Python y no puedo solucionar este error, les explico;

Tengo este código:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

encabezado=['RFC','EMP','COMPROBANTE','TIPO','CPT','IMPORTE','ANIO','QNA','PTDA','C1','C2','PRDNAME'
            ,'COL','C3']


file=pd.read_csv('TRA.csv',low_memory=False,sep=",",names=encabezado)
df = pd.DataFrame(file)
conceptos= df['TIPO'].map(str)+df['CPT'].map(str)
df.loc[:,'COLUMNAS'] = conceptos;
print(df)
df.to_csv('TRA1321_2.csv',sep=',')
```

Mi variable encabezado contiene el nombre de las columnas de mi DataFrame, columnas que más tarde trato de concatenar y escribir en un nuevo archivo, el detalle es que no respeta los ceros que tienen algunos datos al inicio y aún a eso, convierte a float los valores enteros, les muestro:

Mi archivo csv original:

```
SARS751009J27,2000003369,701457548,1,37,   6299.99,2021,13,TP,,,PRDE130,000001,
SARS751009J27,2000003369,701457548,2,01,    1430.7,2021,13,TP,,,PRDE130,000001,
OEGC8105169P5,2000503934,701457549,1,30,     558.4,2021,13,BR,,,PRDE130,000002,
OEGC8105169P5,2000503934,701457549,2,01,    119.26,2021,13,00,,,PRDE130,000002,
```

El archivo que genera este script:

```
,RFC,EMP,COMPROBANTE,TIPO,CPT,IMPORTE,ANIO,QNA,PTDA,C1,C2,PRDNAME,COL,C3,COLUMNAS
0,SARS751009J27,2000003369.0,701457548.0,1.0,37,6299.99,2021.0,13.0,TP,,,PRDE130,1.0,,1.037
1,SARS751009J27,2000003369.0,701457548.0,2.0,01,1430.7,2021.0,13.0,TP,,,PRDE130,1.0,,2.001
2,OEGC8105169P5,2000503934.0,701457549.0,1.0,30,558.4,2021.0,13.0,BR,,,PRDE130,2.0,,1.030
3,OEGC8105169P5,2000503934.0,701457549.0,2.0,01,119.26,2021.0,13.0,00,,,PRDE130,2.0,,2.001
```

Además que numera mis columnas y recorre todo.

Pueden ayudarme a solucionarlo? No encuentro cómo hacerlo, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolví mi problema, el detalle estaba en que no tenía controlado los valores vacío o NaN, por ello de alguna forma se cambiaban los valores.

Me di cuenta de ello porque eliminé las columnas vacías manualmente y el archivo fue cargado de forma correcta.

Entonces leí la documentación de pandas y encontré lo siguiente que lo traduzco a groso modo aquí:

**‎keep_default_na‎‎bool, true predeterminado‎**
‎Si se deben incluir o no los valores de NaN predeterminados al analizar los datos. Dependiendo de si se pasa ‎‎na_values,‎‎ el comportamiento es el siguiente:‎

**‎Si ‎‎keep_default_na‎‎ es True** y se ‎‎especifican na_values,‎‎ ‎‎na_values‎‎ se anexa a los valores de NaN predeterminados utilizados para el análisis.‎

‎**Si ‎‎keep_default_na‎‎ es True** y no se ‎‎especifican na_values,‎‎ solo se utilizan los valores de NaN predeterminados para el análisis.‎

**‎Si ‎‎keep_default_na‎‎ es False** y se ‎‎especifican na_values,‎‎ solo se utilizan los valores de NaN especificados ‎‎na_values‎‎ para el análisis.‎

‎**Si ‎‎keep_default_na‎‎ es False** y no se ‎‎especifican na_values,‎‎ no se analizará ninguna cadena como NaN.‎

Aquí dejo el enlace para que le den una leída si gustan:

[pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Por lo tanto, lo único que hice fue modificar y/o agregar esta línea para que tomara en cuenta los NaN en el análisis de los datos:

```
file=pd.read_csv('TRA.csv',low_memory=False,sep=",",names=encabezado,keep_default_na=False)
```